# Ubuntu missing from boot menu after setting up dual boot

Tags: 11.10, installation, dual-boot

I just installed 11.10 on my Lenovo z570 with 750GB HDD via a USB. After the installation when I turn the computer on I don't get an option to choose the operating system and when I check the HDD in windows it will state the hard drive is 370GB instead of 750.

The installation ate away 300 GB.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Boot-Repair, it will auto repair and fix the existing OS boot.
Type this in terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Boot-Repair can be installed & used from any Ubuntu session (normal session, or live-CD, or live-USB). PPA packages are available for Ubuntu 10.04, 10.10, 11.04 and 11.10.

Using Boot-Repair

```
gksu boot-repair
```

Then try "Recommended repair" button. When repair is finished, reboot and check if you recovered access to your OSs.

The option "**Recommended repair**" will auto search existing boot OS and will auto fix the boot records.

For more option, you can set, look at the GUI interface:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix for many dual boot problems is updating your Grub (Grub is the bootloader - GRand Unified Bootloader)

Try this:

1. Open a terminal by pressing **ctrl+alt+t** or open your unity dash and start typing "**terminal**"
2. Type/copy:

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```

That should add the windows entry, let us know if not and we'll try some other options.